# How to handle bracket field arrays in Symfony REST API

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I'm setting up a REST API using Symfony 3, and I can't get the array values send through a form, the latter being seen as not submitted in my controller.

The use case is to send an array of keywords through a POST form to a /media/keywords endpoint. Then, the endpoint would be able to get every single keyword and ac accordingly. There is no Doctrine entity to be involved here.

My action is as follow :

```
/**
 * @Post(
 *    path = "/media/keywords",
 *    name = "app_media_keywords_update"
 * )
 * @View(StatusCode = 200)
 * @RequestParam(name="keywords")
 */
public function keywordsAction(Request $request)
{
    $form = $this->createFormBuilder()
        ->add('keywords', TextType::class)
        ->getForm();
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    echo "issub=".$form->isSubmitted()."<br>";
    echo "isValid=".$form->isValid()."<br>";

    die();
}
```

the output is as follow :

```
issub=
<br>isValid=
<br>
```

For testing purpose, I'm using Postman to simulate the POST submission as follows:

[image: Adding the keywords using POSTMAN]

I don't understand why the form is seen as not submitted. Is something else needed ? Is my call to createFormBuilde() incorrect (in particular in respect with type, not being an array, only a TextType) ?

Comment: Several items are a collection. Type for collection is `CollectionType`. Also learn how to check form errors.

Answer (score 0):

As you pass several items via `keywords`, you should use [`CollectionType`](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/reference/forms/types/collection.html):

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder()
    ->add('keywords', CollectionType::class, [
        'entry_type' => TextType::class
    ])
    ->getForm();
$form->handleRequest($request);

echo "issub=".$form->isSubmitted()."<br>";
echo "isValid=".$form->isValid()."<br>";

// also get form submit errors, for example:
if (!$form->isValid()) {
    print_r($form->getErrors(true));
}
```

Form errors manual is [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/form.html#accessing-form-errors).

Comment: Looks more logical indeed, but I'm afraid the result of the echo commands still remain the same. As the  print_r(), I suspect circular references because the POST query never returns.